# Highlight paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

Code to highlight italic text:

```
Sub Bold_Italic()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

    rng.Find.ClearFormatting
    rng.Find.Font.Italic = True
    rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    rng.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
    rng.Find.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    With rng.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    rng.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

How can i highlight the whole paragraph or make selected for a paragraph?
Actually, i want to copy and paste paragraph by paragraph to another document.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `range.select`

```
Sub Macro()
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
        Dim range As range
        Set range = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).range

        'range.Characters.Count > 1 means there is text in the paragraph
         If range.Characters.Count > 1 Then
         'Handle the desired operation with the paragraph text
            range.Select
            MsgBox (range.Text)
         End If
    Next i
End Sub
```